# Overfit model after introduce dropout=0.5

Tags: machine-learning

I am facing a problem where my validation loss stagnates after 20 epochs. The training loss keep reducing which makes my model overfit. I have tried dropout with a value of 0.5 but there is no change in validation loss. Besides that, I have done activity regularization on the dense layer and add number of hidden layer but validation loss remain unchanged. How do I reduce my validation loss? I am looking forward for opinion and suggestion.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Are you using cross validation (k-folds etc)? if not, maybe you could check if your test/validation set is differently distributed as your trainings set, if you haven't done that already. This is because it seems very strange to me, that there is no change at all on your validation loss.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.The test and training set were uniformly distributed using kennard stone algo. No change on validation loss make me worry. Do you have any suggestion to cater this problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of data are you training on? it's "business data" right? How many features do you have and what happens, if you increase `alpha`?

Comment: it is not a business data but the data from electronics sensor..i will try data preprocessing to optimize the model.

Comment: Is the data normalized?

Comment: i have normalized my data using standard scaler